# How to dynamically load a partial view without using a controller?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

There is a big chunk of html + js code. The goal is to load and show it only on a specific button click, so, there is no need in pre-loading it every time.

Normally, we can include a partial view dynamically by using jquery/ajax, but as far as I know it requires a controller. In this scenario, there is no need for a controller, as the data is static.

So, the question is: is it possible on a specific event (like button click) to include a partial view without going through a controller?

What we tried was giving the ajax request an address of partial view. However it didn't help.

```
<div class="reportWindow"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#feedback").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Content("_Feedback")",
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#reportWindow").html(result);
            }
        });
    });    
</script>
```

Comment: You can load a static .html document without needing a controller.

Comment: qbantek, how can I make it upon button click? @Html.RenderPartial doesn't fit, as it will render when page is loaded.

Comment: @Bassam already answered how to do it (sorry I was in a hurry that is why i left a comment for others to extend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a Partial view that have `cshtml` extension is still a Razor view, even if the content inside of it is static, the server still needs to read it and convert its content to html (even if that means copy it exactly the way it is and send it back)

What you need is an `html` file, which in turn you can load dynamically with javascript or jQuery:

```
$("#feedback").click(function () {
    $("#reportWindow").load('feedback.html'); 
});
```

Note that this will still ask the server for feedback.html, typically this won't match to any route then IIS will resolve the request by looking for a static pages called feedback.html!